# ImportError when importing from Bio.PDB

Tags: biopython

I want to use Biopython's PDBParser to download PDB files, but this error appears when I try to import it:

> Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:\Python27\TAREA 3 FINAL.PY", line 33, in [HTML] from Bio.PDB import * File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Bio\PDB_init_.py", line 15, in [HTML] from PDBParser import PDBParser File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Bio\PDB\PDBParser.py", line 13, in [HTML] import numpy ImportError: No module named numpy

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Biopython requires the [numpy](https://numpy.org/) module. You need to install numpy in order to use Biopython. You can find the latest version [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.6.2/).